# Plot confidence boundary from 2 signals

Tags: matlab, time-series, curve-fitting, confidence-interval

I have a plot from two signals. On x axis time and on y axis yaw rate. Now I need to plot confidence boundaries (upper and lower) of graph according to confidence interval 95%.  It should be like this:

[image]

but how should I start?

I loaded my yawrate and size. They have (1080 1) as size and just vectors, and if call yawrate it looks like in photo.

```
N = size(yawrate,1);   

yMean = mean(yawrate);                                 
ySEM = std(yawrate)/sqrt(N);                             
CI95 = tinv([0.025 0.975], N-1);                    
yCI95 = bsxfun(@times, ySEM, CI95(:));           
figure
plot(x, yMean)                                      
hold on
plot(x, yCI95+yMean)                                
hold off

grid
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFiqk.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. For people to help you, you need to post your code so far, and the results you get from it, plus any error messages. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you should ask about 95% confident interval of one statistical signal. In that case, I assume for each time point you have two samples. Then the confident interval at that time point is the mean of samples +- 2 standard error. If you do that for all time point, you can generate a upper and a lower bound for your statistical signal.

Comment: From your plot. Each time point should have different interval. For example, the interval at t=10 is much smaller than t=11. What you need to do is calculate the interval for each time point. As for the 2SE rule of thumb is a good “quick and dirty” approximation to the 95% confident interval. SE is estimated from the data as the sample standard deviation divided by square root of the sample size.

Comment: my time data size is 1800 1. How can i calculate the interval for each time point? Is there a code ?

Comment: i don’t know if there exists any function. But it’s easy to implement by ur self. For a specific time point t, all you need to do is get SE statistics from multiple measurements.  The most important thing, to get the interval, you need multiple measurements at a time point.